# Disable transparency mplayer in script

Tags: 11.10, scripts, mplayer

I am working on a short script that will allow me to use video files as a background using mplayer. The code i've got so far is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if zenity --question --title="Run movie as desktop background?" --text="This script will allow you to play a movie on the desktop within your XGL environment.\n\nClick the OK button and choose the movie from the file selection."
then
xwinwrap -ni -o 0.6 -fs -s -sp -st -b -nf -- mplayer -loop 0 -wid WID "`zenity --file-selection`"
fi
```

The problem is that when using the script the desktop and stuff on it are still visible (see image) and i'm looking for the code to disable the transparency. Thanks in advance and greetings from tinuz :)

[image: mplayer transpareny problem]

Answer (score 1):

After some searching and testing i found the right options combo and thought it would be nice to answer my own question for those with the same problem :)

Working code is:

```
xwinwrap -g -ni -fs -s -st -sp -b -nf -- mplayer -loop 0 -wid WID "`zenity --file-selection`"
```